# Styled Components (Material Icons) with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, google-material-icons

I wanna create an element with Styled Components so I can ditch de .tsx react one, where I can set the props to an  element as the same time as I can define a className to it using the attrs. The VSCode is telling me something is wrong with the code bellow

'An instantiation expression cannot be followed by a property access.'

```
export default styled.i<MetaIconProps>.attrs({
  className: 'material-icons'
})`
  width: ${(props) => getSize(props.size)};
  height: ${(props) => getSize(props.size)};
  font-size: ${(props) => getSize(props.size)};
`;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: An instantiation expression cannot be followed by a property access.

Comment: Don'y you have to pass the prop factory ? Check the examples here -> https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs

Comment: as 'styled.i<MetaIconProps>.attrs(props => ({...'? Same problem. I guess because of the Props interface